# Subtyping in Java results in unexpected output

Tags: java, oop, subtyping

I try to understand how subtyping and inheritance works in Java. Recently I ran into a situation that confuses me. I have got the following Code with three classes:

```
class Super{
    String i = "Variable of superclass";
    void m() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}



class Sub extends Super{
    String i = "Variable of subclass";
    
    /*@Override
    void m() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }*/

}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.m();    //Prints Variable of superclass
    }   
}
```

I am so confused with the output of m(). I just don't understand why the method, which is called on an instance of Sub, uses the variable of the superclass. I guess it has to do with variable hiding / shadowing but I can't figure out what is going on there in detail. If I do something like

```
Super sup = new Sub();
sup.m();
```

then I understand, why it prints the variable of the superclass. That's because variables are bound in a static way which I know as variable hiding / shadowing. But I really don't get, what happens in my example.

I was even more confused about what happened when I removed the comment in Sub. I understand that the method is now overridden but I don't get why the method now uses the variable of the subclass even though it's exactly the same code that would have been inherited if I left the comment. I mean, it was already there! How does overriding a method with the exact same code change anything?

I also tried adding `System.out.println(this.getClass.getName());` inside the method to make sure that the method is really called on an instance of sub. And yes, it is.

If anyone could help me out understanding, what's going on here, I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods can be overriden, but fields cannot. `Sub` does not define a `m` method, so `sub.m();` calls the `m` method from `Super`. In the scope of that method, only the `i` field defined in `Super` itself is visible.

The `i` field defined in `Sub` is a distinct field that shadows the field from the superclass of the same name. If you had instead defined a `getI()` method in both `Super` and `Sub`, calling `getI()` in `Super` (when the underlying instance is of type `Sub`) would use the method defined in `Sub`.

Comment: Sub does not define a m method, so sub.m(); calls the m method from Super. That means, that overriding a method with exactly the same code is actually different from just using the inherited method because they have different scopes?

Comment: @Jan Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I hit return to get into a new line but posted the comment instead. I edited it.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it would be different. The methods can access different fields/variables.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand it now. I always thought inheriting a method would be the same as copy and paste the code. That seems to be my mistake. It is actually like overriding m in sub and just calling super.m() inside this overriden method. Now I wonder of it's even correct to say that sub.m() means that I am calling m on an instance of sub. Isn't it more like calling m on some instance of super? Because System.out.println(sub.i) actually prints the 'right' variable.

Comment: @Jan It is fine to say it's calling `m` on `sub`, but which method is actually called depends on the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Or does the object sub have both variables, one of the superclass (wich is hidden when trying to access from inside the subclass) and one of the subclass (wich is not visible for the superclass methods)?

Comment: @Jan There are indeed two fields. You can use `super.i` inside `Sub` to access the field of the superclass.

Comment: Two fields with the same name.... I assumed that there would only be the new variable that hides the superclass variable. That made me wonder were the superclass method called on sub does get the value from. Now everything makes sense to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable with the same name in a subclass (in this case, `Sub`) that already exists in the superclass (in this case, `Super`), it's what we call **variable hiding**.

This means that **the variable declared in the subclass is different from the variable declared in the superclass**, and the subclass **is not overriding** the variable from the superclass but rather **creating a new variable with the same name**.

You can override the `m()` method (as it is in your example code), but you can also just **change the value** using constructors:

**Super Class**

```java
class Super {
    // Final to make sure value is always set
    final String i;

    // Default constructor
    Super() {
        this("Variable of superclass");
    }

    // Use to overwrite
    Super(String i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    void m() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

**Sub Class**

```java
class Sub extends Super {
    Sub() {
        super("Variable of subclass");
    }
}
```

Check this out:

- [Variable Hiding and Variable Shadowing in Java](https://www.scaler.com/topics/java/variable-hiding-and-variable-shadowing-in-java/#example-of-variable-hiding)
- [Variable and Method Hiding in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-method-hiding#hierarchy)